# Generic constraint between two properties of an object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to improve types for a frontend route config object. I'm trying to tie the `path` and `prepare` fields together so that the `prepare` function field receives the appropriate parameters based on the `:keys` in the path.

Each route item in the config (other fields omitted for brevity) looks something like this:

```
interface Routes<Path extends string> {
    path: Path;
    prepare?: (params: PathArgs<Path>) => object;
    routes?: Routes[];
}
```

The helpers used to extract the params from the path string are

```
type PathParams<
  Path extends string
> = Path extends `:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
  ? Param | PathParams<Rest>
  : Path extends `:${infer Param}`
  ? Param
  : Path extends `${infer _Prefix}:${infer Rest}`
  ? PathParams<`:${Rest}`>
  : never;

type PathArgs<Path extends string> = { [K in PathParams<Path>]: string };

// { siteId: string }
type x = PathArgs<`/dashboard/sites/:siteId`>
```

Ideally, if I did something like

```
const routes: Routes[] = [
  {
    path: `/dashboard/:siteId`,
    prepared: (params) => {...},
    routes: [
      { 
        path: `/dashboard/:siteId/widgets/:widgetId`,
        prepared: (params) => {...}
      },
      {
        path: `/dashboard/:siteId/friend/:friendId`,
        prepared: (params) => {...}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The type of `params` would automatically be known to be `{siteId: string}` in the first route, `{siteId: string, widgetId: string}` for the second route, and `{siteId: string, friendId: string}` for the second route.

The type declaration I have above for `Routes` constrains the path and prepare fields correctly for a single object, but does not handle the recursive nature of the config object where it can be a different generic for each nested route, since each path is unique. I'm wondering if this is possible in TypeScript.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukDOAeABTjAAtkIAPSEAEx2RzClAHNkBeBp1gPmQG8AUMmQAHYiQBcyIqQDcwsVAjjlAfmkAKVXAC2OabJIBBKC3xGeASg590AIwBWEBGAUioWXBrReIOAG0AXQUAX0FBMABPURQjIig9fEUjcioIWnpGZhAWRT5OVMpqOmQAA0kAEn5QGGgZOETdUIB6atr61H8wULLFNQam5AAfBtIEpLwuxh5FQwk0kvoK9pA6qEG9Xv7N3TmxsmKM0rLV9eQAfQJlGGAKUKqatc7u7ZEB+MbJlf5pnrLZiJpCAIAA3aAKSIxOISUzmQgLI6ZLg5FgFATIAIAaWQoAOE30CNIPCC0myrGQoUhLRaGJwwEgAEkaGTuLlKVDYsgKBwDnD8GUWjQ4DgSPZ0I0aC16bgWpIZRBmQCIjTkAB1ODgco6fRlZDRLlgdDIewoDpQZQ0ZCIBDoKA0ClG-UkFA0KIgPTABBiO1gYDoED0dAwZ0ocSkQSqgDuDJIeNIKBwehQABswRAU8hg6Gs04XGAAHSCW2BsDITzYfzSDCVwJBXkBRRCEQicNScpCkViiX2uUKpUAGkUreUqggLOQ2i++hs7D4-FCQ5b5b8Bkxw5b-GQG+XbekguFovFkr7DMVUpjNBYEDAODll+vYEHO5bolHjXHWh1OFn8-Cy5ERcX2bADWwkfdOyPHspXlM9mRaGBmGOOVEOAY5n1AkcVA-CcpyaH9bAEf8AOIkQgkUcIgiAA) with the above code included

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NrK53m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simplest solution here is to create builder function and create something similar to linked list data structure.
Consider this exmaple:

```js
interface Route<Path extends string> {
  path: Path;
  prepare(params: PathArgs<Path>): void;
}

type PathParams<
  Path extends string
  > = Path extends `:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
  ? Param | PathParams<Rest>
  : Path extends `:${infer Param}`
  ? Param
  : Path extends `${infer _Prefix}:${infer Rest}`
  ? PathParams<`:${Rest}`>
  : never;

type PathArgs<Path extends string> = { [K in PathParams<Path>]: string };

type ValidRoute = `/${string}/:${string}`

const route = <
  Path extends string,
  Routes extends Route<`${Path}${ValidRoute}`>[]
>(
  path: Path,
  prepare: (param: PathArgs<Path>) => void,
  ...routes: Routes
) => ({
  path,
  prepare,
  routes
})

const routes = <
  Str extends string,
  Elem extends Route<Str>[]
>(...elems: [...Elem]) =>
  elems

const result = [
  route(`/dashboard/:siteId`, (arg) => { },
    route(`/dashboard/:siteId/friend/:friendId`, (arg) => { }),
    route(`/dashboard/:siteId/widgets/:widgetId`, (arg) => { },)
  ),
  route(`/menu/:optioId`, (arg) => { },
    route(`/menu/:optioId/select/:selectId`, (arg) => { })
  )
]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkM0DN)

Arrl `arg` arguments are infered properly. No need to create complicated recursive data structure.
Try to put `/menu/:optioId/select/:selectId` into `dashboard` namespace:

```js
const result = [
  route(`/dashboard/:siteId`, (arg) => { },
    route(`/dashboard/:siteId/friend/:friendId`, (arg) => { }),
    route(`/dashboard/:siteId/widgets/:widgetId`, (arg) => { },),
    route(`/menu/:optioId/select/:selectId`, (arg) => { }) // error
  ),
]
```

You will get an error, because `dashboard` namespace expects strings with `dashboard`.