# How does React Router infer strongly typed arguments from path string?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-router, intellisense

*(This is a question for understanding the workings, not a "how do I..." question)*

When working with React Router I've realized that Vscode IntelliSense can suggest me strongly-typed parameters when I type them in a route like this:

`<Route path='/users/:userId?' render={props => <UserManager selectedId={props.}/>} />`

When I type `props.match.params.`, whenever I have in `path` string as `:text` goes as a strongly typed parameter from inside the string to the params as a strongly typed property (and an optional parameter if there is a question mark as in my case):

[image]

How can Vscode/TypeScript/React Router generate a strongly typed argument from a bare user-entered string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70885329/generic-constraint-between-two-properties-of-an-object/70899862#70899862) question just for reference.

You will find explanation in comments:

```js
import React from 'react'

type PathParams<
  Path extends string
  > =
  /**
   * Check whether provided argument is valid route string with parameters 
   */
  (Path extends `:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
    /**
     * If yes, call PathParams recursively with rest part of the string 
     * and make it union with current param
     */
    ? Param | PathParams<Rest>
    /**
     * Otherwise, check if argument is standalone parameter, for instance ":userId"
     */
    : (Path extends `:${infer Param}`
      /**
       * If yes, return it
       */
      ? Param
      /**
       * Otherwise check if provided string is allowed route string
       * but without /, for instance "user:userId"
       */
      : (Path extends `${infer _Prefix}:${infer Rest}`
        /**
         * If yes, call recursively PathParams with this parameter
         */
        ? PathParams<`:${Rest}`>
        /**
         * If provided string is invalid - return never
         */
        : never)
    )
  )

/**
 * As you might have noticed, we ended up
 * with union of strings. Now we just need to convert this union
 * into record. It is the easiest part
 */
type Params = PathParams<":siteId/user/:userId">

/**
 * Convert union to record with appropriate keys
 */
type PathArgs<Path extends string> = { [K in PathParams<Path>]: string };

// type Result = {
//     siteId: string;
//     userId: string;
// }
type Result = PathArgs<"/dashboard/:siteId/user:userId">
```

Now lets try to build similar react component:

```js
type Props<Path extends string> = {
  path: Path,
  params: PathArgs<Path>
}

const Route = <Path extends string>(props: Props<Path>) => {
  return null
}

const jsx = <Route path="/dashboard/:siteId/user:userId" params={{ siteId: 'hello', userId: 'world' }} /> // ok
const jsx_ = <Route path="/dashboard/:siteId/user:userId" params={{ siteId: 'hello' }} /> // error, missing userId prop
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4XrN)

This example should give you a clue how it is done in react router. I know that my example does not reflect 100% same behavior, still I believe it is helpful

Please keep in mind, that my example is much smaller than actual implementation.

Original implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L408) with comments. Their implementation is much bigger because there might be a lot of edge cases.

Comment: Oh. `infer` inside string template. That clarifies it a lot. didn't know that it could be done. it also opens more possibilities not just path param extraction. Thank you!

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu if you are interested in static type validation of arguments you can check [this](https://catchts.com/type-negation) and [this](https://catchts.com/validators)

Comment: Now I know what will my next quick read be! :)